# Dragstart event breaks the sequence

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Below is my code:

```html
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.list1">
    <tr data-bind="event:{dragstart: $root.dragStart, dragend: $root.dragEnd}" draggable="true">
        <td data-bind="text: Id"> </td>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"> </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table border="1" data-bind="event:{drop: $root.dragDrop, dragover: $root.dragOver}">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.list2">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Id"> </td>
        <td data-bind="text: Name"> </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

```javascript
var MyViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.init = function () {
      // Seed some data to list1 and list2.
    }
    self.list1 = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.list2 = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.draggingValue = null;


    self.dragStart = function(customer){
       console.log('dragstart');
    };

    self.dragEnd = function(){
      console.log('dragend');
    };

    self.dragDrop = function(){
       console.log('dragdrop');
    };
    self.dragOver = function(){
        console.log('dragover');
    };
}

var Customer = function (Id, Name) {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable(Id);
    self.Name = ko.observable(Name);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.init();
    ko.applyBindings(model);
});
```

When I run this page, the console only shows dragstart. If I change my html this way:

```html
<tr data-bind="event:{dragend: $root.dragEnd}" draggable="true" ondragstart='console.log("dragstart")'>
```

then my code works fine. I think this problem is caused by KO.

Comment: give us a sample fiddle with code . cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handlers [need to return true](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html#note-3-allowing-the-default-action) or they will prevent the default action.

```
self.dragStart = function (customer) {
    console.log('dragstart');
    return true;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j35kfgdx/